# Drop-down Menu Not Showing Sub Menus (Template)

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

I am modifying a W3Layouts. The drop-down menu on the template and after several modification still isn't working. I have been working for hours and I cannot seem to get the child menu to drop-down. Thanks for the help provided. My apologies in any mistakes I've made in formatting this question.

```
<!--start header-->
<div class="h_bg">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">
                     <a href="index.html"><img class="hideOnMobile" src="images/logoHRCC_275x275px.png" alt="" /> </a>
                     <a href="index.html"><img class="hideOnDesktop mobileStyle" src="images/logoHRCC_275x275px.png" alt="" /> </a>
                </div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>


              <div class="cssmenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="garage.html"><span>Garage</span></a></li>
                        <li class="has-sub"><a href="join.html"><span>Connect</span></a>                                                                                        
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="eventCalendar.html"><span>Event Calendar</span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                       <li><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
                                       <li class="last"><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 2</span></a></li>
                                    </ul> 
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="join.html"><span>Membership</span></a>
                                    <ul> 
                                       <li><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 1</span></a></li>
                                       <li class="last"><a href="service.html"><span>Sub Item 2</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li><a href="join.html"><span>Vendor Registration</span></a>
                                <li><a href="join.html"><span>Venue Sponsorship</span></a>
                                <li><a href="join.html"><span>Show Registration</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="eventCalendar.html"><span>Calendar</span></a></li>
                        <li class="last"><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




 .cssmenu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: #f6f6f6; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 1%, #f0f0f0 19%, #efefef 39%, #ededed 59%, #dddddd 98%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(19%,#f0f0f0), color-stop(39%,#efefef), color-stop(59%,#ededed), color-stop(98%,#dddddd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 1%,#f0f0f0 19%,#efefef 39%,#ededed 59%,#dddddd 98%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 1%,#f0f0f0 19%,#efefef 39%,#ededed 59%,#dddddd 98%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f6f6f6 1%,#f0f0f0 19%,#efefef 39%,#ededed 59%,#dddddd 98%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f6f6f6 1%,#f0f0f0 19%,#efefef 39%,#ededed 59%,#dddddd 98%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f6f6', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.cssmenu > ul > li.active a{
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #9d9d9d; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%, #8d8d8d 40%, #7d7d7d 68%, #6d6d6d 82%, #5d5d5d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%,#9d9d9d), color-stop(40%,#8d8d8d), color-stop(68%,#7d7d7d), color-stop(82%,#6d6d6d), color-stop(100%,#5d5d5d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9d9d9d', endColorstr='#5d5d5d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.cssmenu > ul > li span img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #161616;
    line-height: 3.8em;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    -webkit-transition: color .15s;
    -moz-transition: color .15s;
    -o-transition: color .15s;
    transition: color .15s;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.9s;
    -moz-transition: 0.9s;
    -o-transition: 0.9s;
    transition: 0.9s;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #9d9d9d; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%, #8d8d8d 40%, #7d7d7d 68%, #6d6d6d 82%, #5d5d5d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(5%,#9d9d9d), color-stop(40%,#8d8d8d), color-stop(68%,#7d7d7d), color-stop(82%,#6d6d6d), color-stop(100%,#5d5d5d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #9d9d9d 5%,#8d8d8d 40%,#7d7d7d 68%,#6d6d6d 82%,#5d5d5d 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9d9d9d', endColorstr='#5d5d5d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #5C5C5C;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 34px;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
    transition: all .3s .1s;
}
.cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 65px;
    visibility: visible;    
}
.cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent #5C5C5C transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.cssmenu > ul ul > li {
    position: relative;
}
.cssmenu ul ul a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #5C5C5C;
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
    transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
.cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 190px;
    visibility: visible;
}
.cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
    background: #4F4E4E;
    color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: I have already search W3Layouts website for a fix, but to no avail.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? I can see the submenu to "Connect" drop down just fine. And the subsubmenus...

Comment: It looks like I had an open div tag somewhere. The drop down is working now. Thank you so much.